# How does Pinterest facebook invite box get generated?

Tags: facebook

I have been trying to replicate Pinterest's send message to user using this code:

```js
    FB.ui({
    method: 'send',
    name: 'The Image',
    display: 'popup',
    description: 'Description here',
    link: 'http://www.mywebsite.com/',
});
```

The popup box shows up but I have no control over the description, name, nor the picture showing the user thumbnail.

The popup box shows my website's description, name, and a random image from page.

here is an image http://postimg.org/image/8o01c3vfr/

How do I get a popup to show the user thumbnail and customized description and name?

**Update:** I tried this and still no hope!

```html
<html>
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="app id" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="Your title">
<meta property="og:description" content="Your Desc.">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Z-yBlXMMYWo/UBUYe-Lc46I/AAAAAAAAAxc/VO9XB7Ls-sY/s640/Under+water.JPG">
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Z-yBlXMMYWo/UBUYe-Lc46I/AAAAAAAAAxc/VO9XB7Ls-sY/s640/Under+water.JPG">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="150">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="150">
</head>
<body>

<div id='fb-root'></div>

<script>
  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: "app id", status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true,   frictionlessRequests : true});

};

function send_message() {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'send',
        name: 'The Image',
        display: 'popup',
        description: 'Description here',
        link: 'http://www.website.com/',
        picture: 'http://www.website.com/image.png'
    });
}
</script>
<a href='#' onclick='send_message();'>send</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the url so I can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Try using open graph meta tags in your `<head></head>` block:

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="Your title">
<meta property="og:description" content="Your Desc.">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://YOURWEBSITE.com/YOURIMAGE.png">
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://YOURWEBSITE.com/YOURIMAGE.png">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="150">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="150">
```

Comment: but how does that connect with the body?

Comment: Well from my experience, facebook parser first looks for these tags in the page, if cannot find those tags then read desc, title from page headers and parses the images from the page so you can choose one. you need to put those og meta tags to the page that will be shared. you can generate those dynamically too. A related blog post here : http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags

Comment: I tried it and still shows the info from my domain. please see my update on the post